# Emoji's in Elastic Search - how to allow them to searchable

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, unicode, emoji, elasticsearch-5

I have an Elastic Search application that needs to be able to support searching emoji's like the following emoji

In the MySQL database this emoji is stored as the following

```
ðŸ˜„
```

The Elastic Search instance takes this DB content and will need to retrievable, eg if the user searches for  in the search API above it would need to search for the exact unicode characters above - can anyone suggest any advice on this as this sounds like some custom functionality not built into Elastic Search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write/configure a character filter:

Character filters
First, the string is passed through any character filters in turn. Their job is to tidy up the string before tokenization. A character filter could be used to strip out HTML, or to convert & characters to the word and.

So you can turn emoijs into abbreviations and then store as regular text.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-charfilters.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html